# Convert UK time to South African time in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a football match date and time as UK time.
I am running this service in South Africa so it must display the fixture date and time as South African time. At the moment I am doing this:

```
int kickoffHour = fixture.getTime().getHours() + 2;
```

However - when it reaches end of March 2016 this will have to change again to "+ 1" instead of "+ 2". Now I can't keep changing this so I want something that will automatically pick up that its DST or BST and do the conversion.

I have tried something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
Date date = sdf.parse(fixture.getDate() + " " + fixture.getTime());
```

But that gave me like 2am or something. My date in the database is: 2015-12-16 and the time in the database is 16:00:00 - after parsing I get Wed Dec 16 02:00:00 SAST 2015

Comment: What was the date and time that you checked using `sdf.parse()`

Comment: I added it to the question now

Comment: please check that `fixture.getDate() + " " + fixture.getTime()` is really returning the string you think it is.

Comment: Hard code the value `2015-12-16 16:00:00` instead of `fixture.getDate() + " " + fixture.getTime()` and try once.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are referring to adjustments needed for Daylight Saving Time (DST). You should leave such work to a good date-time library rather than manage these details yourself.

Unfortunately, the old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java are not good. While a valiant effort, they have proven to be troublesome and confusing, flawed in both design and implementation. Avoid java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

By the way, best practice is to do all your business logic, data storage & exchange, and database work in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Use zoned date-time values only when expected by the user or data sink. However, it appears you have been given a string in London time, so let's go with that.

```
String input = "2015-12-16 16:00:00"; // Local date-time in United Kingdom (London).
```

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Never use the 3-4 letter codes commonly seen as they are neither standardized nor unique.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
```

Your string input lacks embedded info about its [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone. So, we will *assume* the String represents local time in [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London). We communicate this assumption to the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), as it would otherwise interpret the incoming String as belonging to the JVM’s current default time zone. Note that java.time uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so rather than alter the formatter we generate a new instance based on values take from the old instance.

```
ZoneId zoneId_London = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/London" );
formatter = formatter.withZone ( zoneId_London ); // Specify the zone by which to interpret this date-time input string as it lacks any offset or time zone info.
ZonedDateTime zdt_UK = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

With a London date-time in hand, we can adjust into a South Africa time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Johannesburg = ZoneId.of ( "Africa/Johannesburg" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_ZA = zdt_UK.withZoneSameInstant ( zoneId_Johannesburg );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " in zone: " + zoneId_London + " = " + zdt_UK );
System.out.println ( "zdt_UK: " + zdt_UK + " adjusted to zone: " + zoneId_Johannesburg + " is: " + zdt_ZA );
```

> input: 2015-12-16 16:00:00 in zone: Europe/London = 2015-12-16T16:00Z[Europe/London]
>
> zdt_UK: 2015-12-16T16:00Z[Europe/London] adjusted to zone: Africa/Johannesburg is: 2015-12-16T18:00+02:00[Africa/Johannesburg]

Lastly, we do most of our work in UTC. For that, extract a `Instant` object which is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt_ZA.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 0):

if `fixture.getDate() + " " + fixture.getTime()` works fine, at the end you will get the `String` as `"2015-12-16 16:00:00"`.

Then I simply format the returning date. Mine works fine..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    Date date = sdf.parse("2015-12-16 16:00:00");
    //Date date = sdf.parse("2016-03-31 23:50:50");

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Johannesburg"));
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
}
```

Output of this code is `2015-12-16 18:00:00`

When I use commented `date` object, result was `2016-04-01 00:50:50`

Comment: @lulu88 this doesn't appear fundamentally any different to your original code, except for the explicit (instead of implicit) selection of Jo'berg time in the output.   Did you verify that the `fixture.getDate() + " " + fixture.getTime()` _input_ to `sdf.parse` is correct, per the comment on your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the time values from the fixture and use calendar to auto convert your time zone. I am keeping in mind that your system timezone matches the expected output timezone. Please check the below code snipet, w/o using fixture object and using hard coded value.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 16);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(2015, 11, 24);

    System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //printing in IST (my local time)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have a Date object from your database.
If you want to print it, use your SimpleDateFormat setting its timezone to South Africa "Africa/Johannesburg" and it will work.

```
Date myDate;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Johannesburg"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(myDate));
```

Comment: you'd think that, but the OP clearly _doesn't_ have a `Date` object to start from.

Comment: If you don't have a `Date`, that's because you use text for that in your database ? Really  ? So anyway, if you want to do that, parse your string date and you're good to go with the code, same answer as Ramesh-X by the way ...